# How to boot on PXE without F12 key

Tags: unix

I want to do a PXE boot in order to install my servers over network.
For now, I have to press F12 key in order to enter the PXE boot menu.
My servers are Dell PowerEdge and HP ProLiant

I thought about modifying the BIOS boot option, but if I do so, the server will always boot on PXE mode. That's a comportment we want to avoid.

Is there a file on the server to modify to autoboot on PXE mode?
Does someone have another idea to skip the F12 part ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What make is your server?

Comment: I have HP ProLiant and Dell PowerEdge

Answer (score 2):

The boot option is completely in control of BIOS. You can configure your BIOS with Boot Priority, i.e., boot from what/which device. You can choose PXE boot as the priority and need not use <kbd>F 12</kbd>.

For HP, they have a scripting tool available. You may refer [HP Scripting Toolkit](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/solutions/info-library/index.aspx?cat=hp_scripting_toolkit#.V4NY1vl97qY).

Not sure about Dell servers. But [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.msdos.programmer/SqtZ85Armh4) discussion may help you.

Comment: But If I do so, I have to reset the option in the BIOS menu after the installation

Comment: Thank you for these information. Nevertheless, I would like to find a more generic solution, if possible. Another issue, I CANT find how to use HP Scripting Toolkit.. Or I'm stupid or the doc isn't clear

Comment: Alright @JérèmLeBlond, all the best!